# 3D vector projection

Tags: vectors

If I have an arbitrary vector in the 3D coordinate plane with given azimuth angle and polar angle with radius r=1, how could I use this information to project this vector onto the three 2D planes?(xy,yz,xz)  There are no specific number available because I need to represent these "component" vectors symbolically rather than numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vector is $$\vec{p} = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}r \cos\theta \cos\varphi \\
r \cos\theta \sin\varphi \\
r \sin\theta \end{matrix}\right]$$
where $-180° \le \varphi \le +180°$ is the azimuth angle, and $-90° \le \theta \le +90°$ the polar angle, then its projection on the $xy$, $xz$, and $yz$ planes are
$$\vec{p}_{xy} = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\0\end{matrix}\right], \quad
\vec{p}_{xz} = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\0\\z\end{matrix}\right], \quad
\vec{p}_{yz} = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right]$$
respectively.

In spherical coordinates,
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
r_{xy} &= r \cos\theta \\
\varphi_{xy} &= \varphi \\
\theta_{xy} &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$ $$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
r_{xz} &= r \sqrt{1 - (\cos\theta)^2(\cos\varphi)^2} \\
\varphi_{xz} &= \begin{cases}
0°, & \cos\varphi \ge 0 \\
180°, & \cos\varphi \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
\theta_{xz} &= \arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1 - (\cos\theta)^2(\sin\varphi)^2}}\right) \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$ $$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
r_{yz} &= r \sqrt{1 - (\cos\theta)^2(\sin\varphi)^2} \\
\varphi_{yz} &= \begin{cases}
+90°, & \cos\varphi \ge 0 \\
-90°, & \cos\varphi \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
\theta_{yz} &= \arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1 - (\cos\theta)^2(\cos\varphi)^2}}\right)
\end{aligned}\right.$$

---

In general, if you have a plane through origin with unit normal vector $\hat{n}$, $\lVert\hat{n}\rVert = 1$, then the projection of $\vec{p}$ on that plane in Cartesian coordinates is $\vec{p}_n$,
$$\vec{p}_n = \vec{p} - \vec{p}\cdot\hat{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!  This is exactly what I needed.  Do you define θ as the angle of elevation/depression from the x or z axis?  It looks like you defined it relative to the x?  I do not mean to correct you just clarifying.

Comment: @EMossel501: $\theta$ is 0° on the $xy$ plane, when $z = 0$; and the sign is the same as the sign of $z$. So, yes, $\theta$ is the angle to the $xy$ plane ("relative to x"). (I do understand what you are referring to: there are two ways of measuring $\theta$: from the equator like in this case, in which case it is $-90° \le \theta \le +90°$; or from the pole, "relative to z", when it is $0° \le \theta \le 180°$.)

Comment: Thank you again for your response.  This was very helpful.  And thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @EMossel501: If this did indeed answer your question, do consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (Accepting indicates to others reading your question, that the asker found the (best) solution in that answer, and therefore helps them choose an answer too. Conversely, if an answer is not accepted, it is understood to mean that either the asker didn't care, or the asker could not solve their problem using the/any answer.) The accept button is the "v"-shaped mark, to the left from top of my answer, below the up arrow, "score", and down arrow.